# Application instance is terminating due to Hibernate session.createQuery()

Tags: crash, jvm

We are facing the web application instance termination at the session.createQuery()

We are using Linux and jboss-4.0.3 AS version as it is giving the below exception 
We are not getting the issue every time we call this but sometimes we are getting.

```
HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplate = HibernateUtil.getHibernateTemplate();
session = hibernateTemplate.getSessionFactory().openSession();
session.createQuery("update  PpmTaridApproveSLAEntity  set slaStartTimeStamp=to_date('"
                                    + slastarttime
                                    + "','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') ,slaEndTimeStamp=to_date('"
                                    + slaendtime
                                    + "','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'),APPROVEDTIME=to_date('"
                                    + approveTime
                                    + "','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'),status ='"
                                    + status + "', source= '" + source
                                    + "',target='" + target
                                    + "',rejectremarks='" + rejectremarks
                                    + "',SLAFINALVAL='" + slafinavalue + "'"
                                    + " ,APPROVED_BY='" + userid + "'"
                                    + " ,USERNAME='" + username + "'"   
                                    + "  where tarid='" + tarid + "'").executeUpdate();
```

After this error jboss instance is getting terminated automatically (JVM is getting crashed). Please find the below JVM log:

```
    2013-03-07 16:41:24,109 WARN  [org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader] Failed to open JAR
    java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:203)
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:132)
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:97)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.openJARs(WebappClassLoader.java:1544)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findResourceInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:1763)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:1570)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:850)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1299)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1181)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:319)
        at com.tcs.telecom.ppm.actions.CrystalBallEmpowerAction.submitCase(CrystalBallEmpowerAction.java:105)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
        at org.apache.struts.actions.DispatchAction.dispatchMethod(DispatchAction.java:274)
        at org.apache.struts.actions.LookupDispatchAction.execute(LookupDispatchAction.java:160)
        at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:419)
        at com.tcs.telecom.ppm.actions.PPMRequestProcessor.processActionPerform(PPMRequestProcessor.java:34)
        at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:224)
        at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1194)
        at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:432)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:810)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:252)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:173)
        at com.tcs.telecom.ppm.filter.SessionIdFilter.doFilter(SessionIdFilter.java:66)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:202)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:173)
        at com.tcs.telecom.ppm.filter.LoginFilter.doFilter(LoginFilter.java:500)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:202)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:173)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:81)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:202)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:173)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:213)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:178)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.CustomPrincipalValve.invoke(CustomPrincipalValve.java:39)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:159)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:59)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:126)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:105)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:148)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:856)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.processConnection(Http11Protocol.java:744)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.PoolTcpEndpoint.processSocket(PoolTcpEndpoint.java:527)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.MasterSlaveWorkerThread.run(MasterSlaveWorkerThread.java:112)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:595)
    2013-03-07 16:41:24,111 WARN  [org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader] Failed to open JAR
    java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:203)
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:132)
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:97)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.openJARs(WebappClassLoader.java:1544)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findResourceInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:1763)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:1570)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:850)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1299)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1181)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:319)
        at com.tcs.telecom.ppm.actions.CrystalBallEmpowerAction.submitCase(CrystalBallEmpowerAction.java:105)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
        at org.apache.struts.actions.DispatchAction.dispatchMethod(DispatchAction.java:274)
        at org.apache.struts.actions.LookupDispatchAction.execute(LookupDispatchAction.java:160)
        at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:419)
        at com.tcs.telecom.ppm.actions.PPMRequestProcessor.processActionPerform(PPMRequestProcessor.java:34)
        at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:224)
        at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1194)
        at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:432)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:810)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:252)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:173)
        at com.tcs.telecom.ppm.filter.SessionIdFilter.doFilter(SessionIdFilter.java:66)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:202)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:173)
        at com.tcs.telecom.ppm.filter.LoginFilter.doFilter(LoginFilter.java:500)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:202)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:173)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:81)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:202)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:173)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:213)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:178)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.CustomPrincipalValve.invoke(CustomPrincipalValve.java:39)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:159)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:59)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:126)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:105)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:148)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:856)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.processConnection(Http11Protocol.java:744)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.PoolTcpEndpoint.processSocket(PoolTcpEndpoint.java:527)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.MasterSlaveWorkerThread.run(MasterSlaveWorkerThread.java:112)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:595)
```

Answer (score 0):

Several times when I have had strange behavior like this, I traced it to duplicate jar files.

In the case of hibernate, it could be that there is a hibernate3.jar file in JBoss and also a hibernate3.jar in one or more of the applications deployed to the server such as war or ear files.  I even had a case where hibernate3.jar was present twice in the same JBoss installation causing issues.